# Rails 7 with Stimulus - is it possible to pass value to server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I am using Rails 7 with Stimulus, would it be possible to have a routine which would find out the current web browser screen width and pass it to the Rails server to use in laying out the page in a certain way?

Is this possible to do this? If so, what approach should I use?

Comment: Why would you pass the screen width to the back for layout ? usually your layout is dealt by CSS (responsive) and JS. Otherwise it is definitely possible to pass data from the view to the server with a `fetch()`

Comment: You would do it by using the `window.resize` event and `window.innerWidth` and then sending the data with AJAX to the backend.  But resending the entire page every time the user resizes their browser is an extremely silly idea. Listen to @Maxence

Comment: I want to use a css grid to show something like 20 fixed width items at a certain width, but want to show a different item on say the second row, all the way to the right - so I want to be able in rails to calculate which cell it would be and output the different code at the appropriate place...